# PresentViewController from NSObject?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, nsobject

Okay so the problem I'm having in one of my functions is when users are logging in through Facebook, and my app is checking wether or not their Facebook username already exists in our app (Parse.com) database.

If so, present a view controller (which is where I'm having a problem since this is in a NSObject) if not, simply write their facebook username to parse username string. Error I get is:                                 No known class method for selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion'

Here is my code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query]; //1
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:me.username];//2
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {//4

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", objects);

        if ([objects count] > 0)
        {
            // LOOKING TO PRESENT VIEW CONTROLLER HERE? 
            //    TRIED:
            //    [self presentViewController:[@"RegisterUsername" animated:YES completion:nil];


        } else {
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:me.username forKey:@"username"];
        }
    } else {
        NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
    }
}];
```

and since this is inheriting from NSObject, it won't allow me to use the presentViewController. Not sure what else to do from here. :-( This view controller was going to make them set a username before continuing with our app. This code is currently in a login function in a header Comms.h (NSOBJECT) for Facebook iOS SDK

Comment: I think I submitted an edit (to fix the code formatting) at the same time as you, and it may have wiped your last edit. Can you double check the last paragraph?

Comment: You need a reference to the current view controller. In some cases, you can pass a reference to the current view controller to this object, either by setting some `weak` `delegate` property, or by just making it a parameter to the method in which you have this code.

Answer (score 1):

NSObject does not declare the method `presentViewController:`. You'll need to add a UIViewController subclass to the window and then present from that. In the completion block of your `dismissViewController` you should remove the parent from the window.

Alternatively you could create a delegate protocol for checking the username and then notify a UIViewController of the need to either set the username internally or present a login view.

Comment: Not sure what you mean as I'm generally new to iOS development. Any examples or points in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Your current code is laid out pretty nicely already, aside from the commented out bit. If you typed all this up yourself I'm pretty impressed (if you're generally new to iOS). On the other hand, if you just copied and pasted this and are trying to figure out the next steps, take a step back for a moment and try to "read" the code and follow it, to make sure you understand exactly what is going on in each line. I want to make sure before we go farther, so you truly understand what you'll be learning instead of just getting something to copy and paste. We have a lot to go over.

Comment: Yes sir, I understand what all of my code is doing as I have wrote it. I ended up actually fixing everything but calling this on the viewDidLoad of the initial viewController load after login. Everything seems to be working good the way I have things going now. Now to figure out how to add in a UITabController correctly.. -.-

Comment: There you go! Glad you got it figured out